# react router v4 about how to match two url with one route and one component

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

Sorry, my english is not good enough.

Version

4.1.1
I want to match two url with one route and one component.
just like below:

http://host:port/test/orders/id-1
http://host:port/test/products/id-1
How can I write the path for Route?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of **[url path parameters](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)** to specify multiple paths matching the same route.

In your case the Route will look like

```
<Route path = "/test/:param/id-1" component={MyComponent}/>
```

In case you only want to match the `/orders/ids-1` and `/products/id-1`, then you can make use of regex in the path param. `react-router` makes use of a path that **[`path-to-regexp`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp)** understands,

The relevant documentation of it is there with the **[react-router documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/path-string)**

So you can use

```
  <Route path = "/test/(orders|products)/id-1" component={MyComponent}/>
```

Comment: Thank you very mush ,but I want the param will be one of [order,product].